# Bootstrap: content in the center

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want everything to be in the center of the page, it also needs to be responsive.

this is my code with PHP, because I'm using a loop to show all the checkboxes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- START FORM -->
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal"> 
        <!-- ROW 1 CHECKBOXES -->
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) { 
        echo "<div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='col-md-2'><input type='checkbox' class='form-
control chk_boxes2' name='check_list[]'></div>
                <label class='col-md-2'>Medewerker</label>        
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4'> 
                <div class='col-md-2'><input type='checkbox' class='form-
control chk_boxes2' name='check_list[]'></div> 
                <label class='col-md-2'>Medewerker</label>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='col-md-2'><input type='checkbox' class='form-
control chk_boxes2' name='check_list[]'></div>
                <label class='col-md-2'>Medewerker</label>
            </div>
            </div>";
    }
?>         
        <!-- ROW SUBMIT -->
        <div class="row down right">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-3">Check all</label>
                <div class="col-md-3"><input type='checkbox' 
class="chk_boxes form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" name="Verder" value="Verder" 
class="form-control btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>
    <!-- END FORM -->
</div>
```

**This is the jQuery I use right now, I know it's nothing solid:**

```
$('.down').css('margin-top', function () {
    return ($(window).height() - $(this).height()) / 2.8
});

$('.right').css('margin-left', function () {
    return ($(window).height() - $(this).height()) / 2
});
```

This is a link to JSFiddle, you do need to expand it because big screens is the main problem here.

https://jsfiddle.net/wq0r0se4/

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try using text-center class  in the parent container of the elements you want centered.

Comment: Do you want to center the content only horizontally? If so, you could just add 'text-center' after your 'form-horizontal' class.

Comment: You have your columns set to medium size screen to be divided as col-md-4, but they will do default behavior in screens large, small and extra small. You need to tell them col-lg-4 col-md-4 will take up 1/3 of the screen in large and medium size screen and col-sm-12 col-xs-12 to take full screen in small and extrasmall screens. That is how it becomes responsive.

Comment: @Rubenxfd both horizontal and vertical. when I add 'text-center' to the form it doesn't do anything except that it moves 'check all' a bit to the right.

Comment: @Rubenxfd what I did was change the grid layout, I made another div at the beginning and I added 'col-md-1' (or 2 depends on how much content) also with lg and sm

Comment: If you want to have the whole form centered on smaller screens, you should try @jmag his solution by adding col-sm-4. Also, I don't know why you chose to give a bootstrap class to the input types as they are already in a div with col-md-4. Perhaps this fiddle is what you meant? https://jsfiddle.net/wq0r0se4/4/

Answer (score 0):

apply `text-align: center` to your `.form-horizontal`

and remove margin left js

Update your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wq0r0se4/1/